# Selecting Minimum Number of Machines that Sum to Meet A Production Output - Simplify Code?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures, simplify

I am trying to determine the minimum number of "machines" that can meet a certain production output. By "rule-of-thumb", a larger machine is a more economical choice than a smaller machine. I believe this can be formulated as an optimization problem or solved using some algorithm I'm unaware of. If there is, I would be grateful for pointers (which algorithm to implement). If not, I was wondering if there was a simpler, more elegant way to solve the problem. I was thinking that there may be an option using mathematical sets, number line objects, etc.

lower = (lower[i],upper[i]) defines the production output range for Machine i.
The index i defines the machine in an OrderedDict outside of this problem. Ie the last index 
corresponds with the last item in the dictionary. This function will return a list of machines of which 
I can then implement using the OrderedDict (which contains other information on the machines).

Excluded error checking to simplify code.

```
lower = [0, 5, 10]
upper = [3, 9, 15]
```

some user defined production value they need

```
prod_value = 4
```

assume all production outputs are integer and discontinuity is allowed (4 isn't in any machine range)

```
def get_machines(prod_value, lower, upper):

        prod_value = prod_value
        lower = lower
        upper = upper

        def in_range(prod_value, lower, upper):
                # Function that returns (machine index, machine output) if it is not greater than max

                for i in range(len(lower)):
                        # within range

                        if prod_value >= lower[i] and prod_value <= upper[i]:

                            return (i,prod_value)

                        # This catches all machines smaller than min or discontinuities 

                        elif prod_value <= lower[i]:

                            return (i, lower[i])
                        else:
                            continue

        machine_list = []

        if prod_value > upper[-1]:

                while prod_value:

                        if prod_value - upper[-1] > 0:

                                prod_value -= upper[-1]

                                machine_list.append((-1,upper[-1]))
                        else:
                                machine_list.append(in_range(prod_value,lower,upper))

                                prod_value = 0 

                return machine_list

        else:
                machine_list.append(in_range(prod_value,lower,upper))   

                return machine_list
```

Comment: In your example, what answer would you want it to return?  The two answers that I see as reasonable are `[0, 0]` or `None` depending on whether you can use a particular kind of machine more than once.

Comment: It would look like:

[(0,0), (0,0)] - > where each element of the list represents the machine. 

The first element of the tuple represents the machine-type, while the second would represent the machine production output. 

A none would be needed as well if no machine is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
import collections
Solution = collections.namedtuple(
            'Solution', 'machine_type production machines previous overproduction')

def optimal_machines (target, lower, upper):
    best = [None for i in range(target+1)]
    best[0] = Solution(
                machine_type=None, production=None, machines=0,
                previous=None, overproduction=0)
    for i in range(target):
        if best[i] is not None:
            soln = best[i]
            for j in range(len(lower)):
                for production in range(upper[j]+1):
                    k = i+production
                    if target < k:
                        break
                    overproduction = soln.overproduction
                    if production < lower[j]:
                        overproduction += lower[j] - production
                        production = lower[j]
                    if best[k] is None or (soln.machines+1, overproduction) < (best[k].machines, best[k].overproduction):                            
                        best[k] = Solution(
                                    machine_type=j, production=production,
                                    machines=best[i].machines+1, previous=best[i],
                                    overproduction=overproduction)

    # We now have the answer as a linked list.  Convert that to the desired format.
    answer = []
    solution = best[target]
    if solution is None:
        return None
    else:
        while solution.machine_type is not None:
            answer.append([solution.machine_type, solution.production])
            solution = solution.previous
        return answer
```

This differs from your existing solution  `target` of `0` or `16+`.  I believe that in both cases my solution is strictly better.